# Gridview is not displaying while i run my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display three column field as dropdownlist and other in textbox format.I have wrote the code to display the dropdownlist value from my database but its not working.I have attached my code for your referal

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FacultyName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblfaculty" runat="server" Text='<%%# Eval("facultyname") %>>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfaculty" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlfaculty_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblsubject" runat="server" Text='<%%# Eval("subject") %>>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsubject" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlsubject_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblsubject" runat="server" Text='<%%# Eval("subject") %>>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsubject" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlsubject_SelectedIndexChanged1"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblsubject" runat="server" Text='<%%# Eval("sethour") %>>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ddlsethour" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcount" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Count" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

### CodeBehind:

```
public partial class transhonorarium : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void ddlfaculty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select facultyname from faculty", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
        cmd.Fill(dt);
        Gv1.DataSource = dt;
        Gv1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void ddlsubject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select subject from assign where facultyname=@facultyname", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
        cmd.Fill(dt);
        Gv1.DataSource = dt;
        Gv1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you show  the `code behind` of the page, Also, did you `bind` your gridview

Comment: You should bind your grid in your Page_Load method or any event.

Comment: in the `ddlsubject_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, you have a parameterized query, but i dont see you asigning this parameter anywhere in your command.

Comment: Also I don't see where your `SqlCommand` gets connection to execute against. That code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change one thing here.

1. `AutoGenerateColumns = true`. Because of this, you will be able to see the columns assigned and its data.

Secondly,

You need to `Bind` your Gridview as required on `Page_load` or somewhere you want. Here is for page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Gv1.DataSource = Somesource;
        Gv1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

See the `Bind Data`

```
public void BindData()
{
    SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Yourtablename", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GV1.DataSource = dt;
    GV1.DataBind();
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Mr.Ehsan Sajjad  i have tried your code but same thing nothing is displaying

Comment: did you tried debugging your code and checked where you are getting error or something

Comment: you have to bind your gridview on page_load, as per your code you have not done that

Comment: Mr.nadeem sorry am new to these can you suggest me how to call that gridview in pageload

Comment: you can see my full code, what I given you as my answer, Try that. I guess it will work

Comment: what is that somesource

Comment: it is datatable object from where you are calling the data from the database

Answer (score 0):

Call the `DataBind()` Method of your Gridview when your data changes.

I'd do something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(Eventargs e)
{
  base.OnPreRender(e);
  GV1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Okay, does your query return any data?

Comment: sorry am new to these can you suggest me how to call that gridview in pageload

Answer (score 0):

in order to fill your dropdown lists ,you should implement _RowDataBound event  and to update dataset bases on your selection you should also implement RowCommand event for your dropdown objects.

btw. in ddlsubject_SelectedIndexChanged, you also need to add parameter to your sql command to  get your sql string working ,

hope this helps.